# polymorphism in java chess game

Tags: java, polymorphism

I am new to java and am trying to build the logic to run a chess game. I have a superclass called 'Piece' and subclasses for king, knight, queen etc. I am trying to implement a move method where I determine the type of piece on the fly and then call that piece's corresponding move method. For example:

```
int typeOfPiece = _board[startX][startY]._theKind;
Piece myPiece;

switch(typeOfPiece)
{
    case 1:
        myPiece = new Pawn(startX, startY, team);
    case 2: 
        myPiece = new Rook(startX, startY, team);
    case 3:
        myPiece = new Knight(startX, startY, team);
}

boolean myPiece.canMove(endX, endY);
```

Is there a way that I can ensure the canMove method will be called by the correct type of piece in this example?

Thanks

Comment: add `break` in your cases and provide a `default` case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override `canMove` in all subclasses and make it abstract in the parent class `Piece`.

Answer (score 4):

If your board would hold `Piece` objects instead of `int` values then you could just do:

```
Piece piece = _board[x][y];
piece.canMove(...);
```

The `Piece` class would define a `canMove` method and all its subclasses would implement using their own Strategy.

Answer (score 0):

If your subclasses override the canMove method on superclass 'Piece' ,myPiece.canMove(endX, endY) will be enough.Based on the object type pointed by the myPiece reference, at runtime jvm will decide which method it should call.This is called dynamic method dispatch

Answer (score 0):

What I would do would be to create an abstract class or interface denoting the behaviour and properties of a `Piece` object.

I would then have classes which implement/extend the piece class, each denoting their own behaviour with a `canMove` method.

You instantiate your objects and then, in your code, you simply get the `Piece` object residing at position (x, y) and call `canMove`. This will delegate the behaviour to the appropriate subclass, leaving your code cleaner, more maintainable and flexible.

Having an abstract class or interface, as opposed to having a concrete class for your `Piece` object, is (in my opinion) advantages since it *forces* each piece to implement such behaviour, rather than simply inherit it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `enum` as a `Piece` factory. That way you avoid the need for `1 means Pawn, ...` etc because you have `Pieces.Pawn` etc. Note that you can still have an `enum` called `Pawn` AND a `class` called `Pawn` with no ambiguities.

```
private abstract static class Piece {
  // Current position.
  protected int x, y;

  // Returns true if this piece could move there.
  abstract boolean canMove ( int x, int y);
}

private static class Pawn extends Piece {
  @Override
  boolean canMove (int toX, int toY) {
    // Not handling en-passant and first-move etc.
    return toX == x && (toY == y + 1 || toY == y + 2);
  }
}
private static class Rook extends Piece {
  @Override
  boolean canMove (int toX, int toY) {
    return toX == x || toY == y;
  }
}

// A Piece factory.
private static enum Pieces {
  Pawn {
    @Override
    Piece make () {
      return new Pawn();
    }
  },
  Rook{
    @Override
    Piece make () {
      return new Rook();
    }
  };

  abstract Piece make();
}

// Make a Piece.
private static Piece makePiece ( Pieces type ) {
  return type.make();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [Enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) which implement an abstract class Piece instead of a 2d array of int to represent the board,[Example](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaGame_TicTacToe.html).You can avoid [magic numbers](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29&ei=oDgBUYztFsb_rAeEn4CgBw&usg=AFQjCNEBrhFvMq4tSp1fmTLhIkLF2eIkMw&sig2=7eHf9J49yaAn7muoGcqKBQ&bvm=bv.41524429,d.bmk) by doing this.

Answer (score 0):

What you did in your question is not really making use of the polymorphism as you are deciding the type of the piece by your program code.

I suggest you change your Desing a bit: Instead of creating a new instance for each piece everytime you try to move it, create two seets of all pieces (black and white). Let the board store the references to the pieces so you can retrieve the instance of the piece directly from the board.

From the abstract base class Piece derrive Pawns and other characters that implement the abstract method canMove()